# Clicking on show modal button toggle id="null" on body

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I added the following bootstrap modal in my site http://jsfiddle.net/aPDVM/4/.

It works on jsfiddle but on my site I get `id="null"` applied on `<body>` when I click on the 'Launch Modal' button. Why is this happening??

```
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Launch Modal</a>

<div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
    <h3>Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it works in jsfiddle is not an usefull example for us. You need to share a MCVE (Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example). Read more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . So your problem is in another code of your site that you don't share

Comment: I can't reproduce my issue on jsfiddle...I asked this question hoping that someone had the same issue and solved it.

Comment: Read the link I share with you. You need to share an example with the problem. If in your site gets the null value, the most probably thing that happens is that in your code there are another kind of operations